# How to keep POJO in .aar

Tags: java, android, proguard, android-proguard, aar

I am new to Android and I am trying to develop a .aar that has some services that send data to a remote server. The problem is that when I try to send data in JSON format, the key names are 'a', 'c' .... 
I know that it is pro guard which is obfuscating the code. 
How can I avoid this?
I tried

```
-keep public class mypackageName.*
```

also

```
-keep public class mypackageName.myClassName**
```

and also

```
-keep public class mypackageName.myClassName{*;}
-keepclassmembers class mypackageName.myClassName{*;}
```

but nothing is working.
Which pro guard should I modify the app one or the .aar one?